# SPARQL for find things within 20km of a resource

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am trying SPARQL with Jena 3.1.0. I have to find resources that are within a 20km radius from each resource obtained from a resource list.

I did this SPARQL Query: [click me](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fresource%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCadogan_Hotel%3E%20geo%3Ageometry%20%3Fsourcegeo%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fresource%20geo%3Ageometry%20%3Flocation%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%20bif%3Ast_intersects%28%20%3Flocation%2C%20%3Fsourcegeo%2C%2020%20%29%20%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D). It works at DBpedia endpoint, but it doesn't work in Java.

Here goes my code.

```
public class SKPQSearch {

    static Model model = getTestModel();
    public static char quotes = '"';
    public static boolean USING_GRAPH = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Resource> interestObject = new ArrayList<Resource>();
        List<Resource> features = new ArrayList<Resource>();

        interestObject = searchObjectofInterest("Hotel");
        features = findFeatures(interestObject);

        Iterator<Resource> it = features.iterator();

        System.out.println("Features.....\n\n");

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next().getURI());
        }                   }

    public static Model getTestModel() {

        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        return model;

    }

    public static List<Resource> findFeatures(List<Resource> interestSet) {

        List<Resource> featureSet = new ArrayList<>();

        String serviceURI = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";

        for (int a = 0; a < interestSet.size(); a++) {

            String queryString = "" + Sparql.addService(USING_GRAPH, serviceURI)
                    + "SELECT DISTINCT ?resource WHERE { <" + interestSet.get(a).getURI()
                    + "> geo:geometry ?sourcegeo." + " ?resource geo:geometry ?location ;" + "rdfs:label ?label ."
                    + "FILTER( bif:st_intersects( ?location, ?sourcegeo, 20 ) )." + "FILTER( lang( ?label ) =" + quotes
                    + "en" + quotes + ")}" + Sparql.addServiceClosing(USING_GRAPH);

            Query query = QueryFactory.create(Sparql.addPrefix().concat(queryString));

            try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {

                Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> serviceParams = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
                Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                values.add("20000");
                params.put("timeout", values);
                serviceParams.put(serviceURI, params);
                qexec.getContext().set(ARQ.serviceParams, serviceParams);
                try {
                    ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();
                    System.out.println(rs.hasNext());
                    for (; rs.hasNext();) {
                        QuerySolution rb = rs.nextSolution();

                        RDFNode x = rb.get("resource");
                        if (x.isResource()) {
                            featureSet.add((Resource) x);
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    qexec.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return featureSet;
    }

    public static List<Resource> searchObjectofInterest(String object) {

        List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();

        String serviceURI = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";

        String queryString = "" + Sparql.addService(USING_GRAPH, serviceURI) + "SELECT distinct ?hotel " + "WHERE {  "
                + " ?hotel a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/" + object + ">. }" + " LIMIT 1"
                + Sparql.addServiceClosing(USING_GRAPH);

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(Sparql.addPrefix().concat(queryString));

        try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)) {

            Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> serviceParams = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
            Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            values.add("20000");
            params.put("timeout", values);
            serviceParams.put(serviceURI, params);
            qexec.getContext().set(ARQ.serviceParams, serviceParams);
            try {
                ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();

                for (; rs.hasNext();) {
                    QuerySolution rb = rs.nextSolution();

                    RDFNode x = rb.get("hotel");
                    if (x.isResource()) {
                        resources.add((Resource) x);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                qexec.close();
            }
            return resources;
        }       }    }
```

Sparql.addService method

```
public static String addService(boolean usingGraph, String serviceURI) {
    if (!usingGraph) {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE { SERVICE <" + serviceURI + ">{";
    } else {
        return " ";
    }
}
```

Query example: [click me](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fresource%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCadogan_Hotel%3E%20%0D%0Ageo%3Ageometry%20%3Fsourcegeo.%20%0D%0A%3Fresource%20geo%3Ageometry%20%3Flocation%20%3B%0D%0Ardfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20%0D%0AFILTER%20%28%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fschema%2Fsparql%2Fextensions%23bif%3Ast_intersects%28%3Flocation%2C%3Fsourcegeo%2C20%29%3E%20%29%0D%0AFILTER%28%20lang%28%20%3Flabel%20%29%20%3D%22en%22%29%7D)

PS: I am using the prefix: `PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>`

Comment: It's not clear what `Sparql.addService` does, but I guess it's somehow generating a federated query? Otherwise, you would run the SPARQL query against an empty model. For debugging purpose, it's much easier if you provide the full final query to see what's really executed.

Comment: Jena does not support GeoSPARQL : it provides a basic spatial search feature. http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html  `bif:st_intersects` isn't GeoSPARQL nor is it Jena - it is Virtuoso specific.

Comment: @AndyS I think he's running a federated query on the DBpedia endpoint, thus, it doesn't matter here. At least that's what I assume when looking at the code, there is some magic line `Sparql.addService(USING_GRAPH, serviceURI)`. Otherwise, the whole query would be run on an empty Jena model.

Comment: Sorry for the mess AndyS and @AKSW. I'm reusing some code to build my own, and the Sparql.addService is some of the reused code. This method is just to switch where the query will be executed: in a RDF graph or DBpedia endpoint. I have updated the question with this method and an example of the full final query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.

For some reason, I can't use the `bif` prefix in `bif:st_intersects( ?location, ?sourcegeo, 20 )`. So I put the full URI `FILTER ( <http://www.openlinksw.com/schema/sparql/extensions#bif:st_intersects(?location,?sourcegeo,20)> )`

EDIT: Following the @TallTed suggestion, I have updated my Sparql.addPrefix() method and put `PREFIX bif: <bif:>` on it. This way I don't have to use the full URI on my SPARQL query.

```
 public static String addPrefix() {
        String prefix = "" + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"                 
                + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "
                + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
                + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> " 
                + "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> "
                + "PREFIX bif: <bif:>"
                + "PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> " 
                + "PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> "
                + "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/> " 
                + "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> "
                + "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>"
                + "PREFIX e: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/expenses#> "
                + "PREFIX d: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#> ";
        return prefix;
```

Comment: You may find that using `+ "PREFIX bif: <bif:> "` brings you success with the CURIe.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @TallTed. It works! But I didn't understand how it works without the link `<http://www.openlinksw.com/schema/sparql/extensions`. I should specify this link somewhere, shouldn't I?

Comment: `bif:` is a built-in Virtuoso prefix (and URI scheme, within SPARQL), standing for `built-in function`.  You only need the `PREFIX` statement for tools that pre-parse your SPARQL, before submitting it to the back-end.  Those tools generally don't check for validity of the expanded CURIe; they just check that there's an expansion to be made.